# Deleting lines ending with period(.) from a file using shell script

Tags: shell, awk, scripting

I am trying to delete lines from a file that ends with period symbol. I am using the following command to do this

```
awk '!/.$/' abc.txt > abcd.txt
```

I tried using below commands as well

```
awk '!/\.$/' abc.txt > abcd.txt
awk '!/\\.$/' abc.txt > abcd.txt
awk '!/[.]$/' abc.txt > abcd.txt
awk '!/[\.]$/' abc.txt > abcd.txt
```

But, still I am getting below error

```
awk: unexpected character '.'
```

**EDIT1:**
If I want to add multiple conditions in awk for the same purpose like 
if a sentence has period symbol (.) or percentage (%) symbol, etc. then remove the line. How could I add multiple conditions in awk?

Could anyone please help me solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep`:

```
grep -v '\.[[:blank:]]*$' file
```

Or this `awk` should also work:

```
awk '!/\.[[:blank:]]*$/' file
```

Or using `sed`:

```
sed -n '/\.[[:blank:]]*$/!p' file
```

Comment: You might be having some strange version of awk as given command works fine for me. Also using `sed` you can do: `sed -n '/\.$/!p' file`

Comment: I realized the issue. It works with the given command. the issue was related to space. my file had same after period (.). Thanks.